# Can I access the stream instance used by BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL?

Tags: c++, boost-log, boost-unit-test-framework

Is it possible to access the underlying stream instance used by BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL?

I'm trying to have BOOST unit test framework write output using BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL (which I have configured to write in a file and std::clog)

auto& log_stream = ??? // BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL stream instance
boost::unit_test::unit_test_log.instance().set_stream(log_stream);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to access the underlying stream instance used by BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL?

No, it's not. Internally, the default sink in Boost.Log, which is used by `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL` unless you configured your own sink, does not even use a stream.

I think, the best way to integrate Boost.Test with Boost.Log is to implement your own stream buffer (a class derived from `std::streambuf`). The buffer would have to convert the output from Boost.Test into separate log records (e.g. by splitting it at newline characters) and pass the records to Boost.Log via `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL` or other means. You can then create a `std::ostream` object referring to your stream buffer and pass it to Boost.Test into `set_stream`.

Comment: Thanks Andrey, implementing my own proxy was my first thought, I just hoped that this might be a common case, already with a solution. It seems not. From what I've seen briefly in the documentation using sinks might be a solution as well, and wouldn't need my own proxies. Not sure if I have time to investigate more the sinks.